# ggplot2: Map geom size to group means within data

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Question**

Is it possible to map an aesthetic to the mean value for each group in a dataset?

**Example**

Map the line width for each continent in `gapminder`, but avoid pre-processing the data to create the group means for this mapping. The following plot is the desired output:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)

ggplot(data = gapminder %>% group_by(continent) %>% mutate(mean_pop = mean(pop)),
       mapping = aes(x = year,
                     y = lifeExp,
                     color = continent, 
                     linetype = continent,
                     size = mean_pop)) +
  geom_line(stat = "summary")
```

[image]

But I want `data` to just take `gapminder` as-is:

```
ggplot(data = gapminder,
       mapping = aes(x = year,
                     y = lifeExp,
                     color = continent, 
                     linetype = continent,
                     ...)) +
  geom_line(stat = "summary")
```

Comment: You can use `aes(size = ave(pop, continent, FUN=mean))`, but really it would be better to summarize your data beforehand. Just let `ggplot` do the plotting and not the data transformation.